# doc view PNG support

Tags: pdf

I'm running a fresh install of Arch Linux and if I try to view a pdf file in doc-view or pdf-view, I get the following error message:

> No PNG support is available, or some conversion utility for pdf files is missing.
>   Unable to render file.  View extracted text instead

A quick web search didn't provide any leads as how to resolve this issue - actually, I don't even know what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Was your Emacs compiled with png-support? (i.e. linked to libpng)

Comment: @asjo The installation was done by pacman. How can I check whether it is linked and how can I link it to libpng, if that's not the case?

Comment: You can check which libraries a binary is linked against by using the ldd(1) command. I don't know how pacman/Arch works, but I guess you need libpng-dev (or whatever the development package for libpng is called in Arch) installed, when compiling Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two possibilities that I see based on the error message are:

1. Emacs was not compiled with png support
2. You do not have a program to convert from pdf to png installed

The ways to check each of these are:

1. Try to open a png in Emacs if you see a picture in image mode (you may need to hit `C-c C-c` or something) then you have png support.
2. Open a terminal and run `gs`. if this program is installed then you should be good. Otherwise, install Ghostscript

If you don't have png support them I don't really know what you can do easily. You may be able to find some distro specific instructions for a more complete installation or you may have to build Emacs yourself.

I should probably add that if you get docview working then you should look into pdftools as it can give you some more advanced pdf-specific features

Comment: Thank you. It was ghostscript that was missing. Installing it resolved the issue.