# Fail to view PDF with pdf-tools

Tags: pdf-tools

I have installed pdf-tools by melpha, and write a line in init.el file to load it. However, when I opened my pdf files I still couldn't view it and the error of "Error running timer ‘pdf-cache--prefetch-start’: (error "PNG image supported not compiled into Emacs")". 
It seems that I didn't have PNG support. When I hit C-c C-c, it shifted into DocView mode. Could anyone give me some suggestions to solve this?

Comment: System, emacs version? There was a similar question here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38946/png-image-support-and-pdftools where OP was able to solve the problem. Also here is a related question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22586/doc-view-png-support

Comment: @andrej Thank you for your reply! I tried the steps in your second post, I haven't figured out what to do with the first one. By the way, I'm using terminal emacs on Mac, will it be a problem?

Comment: Sorry! I'm not familiar with Mac. As far as I understand pdf-tools is not really working in terminal, see https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/260